# Why is code after document.write() not executed?

Tags: javascript

I have the follwing JavaScript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function fdivisible()
            {
                document.write("<h1> Just a javascript demo</h1>");
                var x=document.forms["aaa"]["txt1"].value;  
                alert(x);   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" name="aaa">
            Enter a no. : <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" />
            <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="fdivisible();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, the first line of the JS function is executing and the rest are ignored. If I comment out the first line the rest of the code is executed. Can anybody explain to me why it is so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) can only be used during the initial loading of the document.

If you want to insert your H1 when the function is called, you may replace

```
document.write("<h1> Just a javascript demo</h1>");
```

with

```
var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.innerHTML = " Just a javascript demo";
document.body.appendChild(h1);
```

Answer (score 7):

Because calling [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write) implicity calls [`document.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open), which clears the document on  which it has been called:

> If a document exists in the target, this method clears it

After the call to `document.write`, the element you're trying to get a reference to no longer exists in the DOM, and an error is thrown. If you look in the error console it should be something along the lines of the following:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'txt1' of undefined`

Answer (score 4):

document.write(content) writes content on the document stream.

You have to close the stream after writing on the document in order to continue the page loading

```
document.write("hello");
document.close();
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.close
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open

Comment: Yes, after close(), my jquery function $(function(){...} been called.

Answer (score 1):

With addition to dystroy answer, you could replace `document.write` with:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>Javascript demo</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're destroying the DOM with your document.write call. In some browsers, this also destroys global variables.

Instead use:

```
var element = document.createElement('h1');
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text'));
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `document.write()` at the end of all JS statements. The `script` element is never executed after it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x=document.getElementById(txt1).value;
alert(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write to the document with

```
    document.write("<h1> Just a javascript demo</h1>");
```

only once and it applies to the whole document. If you want to put  you will have to add a class/id to it and then put text in that class/id.