# Trouble calling functions after a Document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, css, document.write

I'm having a problem getting a function to call when I click a button.  The code I'm using is shown below, and has worked on other pages, which is why I'm confused.  Could it be because this code is part of a new page written over the old using Document.write(NewPage), where new page is essentially a php document returned from an ajax post?

```
<div class="abSpec" id="intro" style="display: block; text-align: center;"> 
    <p>Some text</p>
    <input type="button" name="proceed" id="proceed" value="Proceed"/>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#proceed").click(function(){
        document.getElementById('intro').style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't like asking a debug question, but I've tried everything I can think of.

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing closing parentheses. Is that a typo in your question or your code? Your browser should be printing errors about it...

Comment: Fair catch.  I think it's from copying the code over, but I could be wrong.  Browser didn't print any errors like that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` can only be used during the initial page load. See [In JavaScript code after document.write() is not executed why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820535/in-javascript-code-after-document-write-is-not-executed-why)

Comment: So javascript referencing newly written things won't even work?  Wow.  Anyway, I think I found a way around using the document.write().  Thanks!